# Using render_templete and static file, which one is faster in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing an web app using Flask in Heroku. My web will have k news pages. Information for each page is stored in database. When user make a request in web browser, the returned page can be generated using render_templates() in Flask. 
The problem is when all users request same page, render_templates() will be called multiple times for the same page => kind of wasting resources to do the same thing
I curious whether I should use render_templates() or I should generate k static pages and use there static file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Flask-Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) package.

Support [built-in](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#built-in-cache-backends) cache backends  like `dictionary`, `file system`, `memcached`, `redis`, and also [custom](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#custom-cache-backends) cache backends.

Example:

```
@cache.cached(timeout=50)
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

.

```
@cache.memoize(timeout=50)
def big_foo(a, b):
    return a + b + random.randrange(0, 1000)
```

.

```
@cache.cached(timeout=50)
def big_foo():
    return big_bar_calc()
```

Also another option [beside that] is using front page caching, like [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).